# How to get paid providing full node services?

Tags: economic-theory

I run a full node.  I would like to get paid for the services I provide.  How can I go about getting that to happen?

Comment: Maybe you can clarify which of the following you mean: do you want to get paid for the fact that you are running a full node? Or are you offering other services and which to get paid to your qt wallet?

Comment: If you're asking how to get paid for the services a full node provides, you probably can't. There's no shortage of full nodes.

Comment: I would like to see all full node operators get paid for the services they provide.  I have a copy of the blockchain.  Someone wants it or a portion of it.  No problem.  All of the full node operators bid to fulfill the request.  The winner (maybe the lowest bid or higher quality service) gets paid.  As the blockchain gets bigger and bigger eventually unpaid full node operators will begin to drop off the network.

Comment: @DavidRabahy: Maybe you should check out something like NXT where you can use proof-of-stake to get paid. Bitcoin won't cut it. In Bitcoin, only Chinese factory owners get paid.

Answer (score 3):

Presently, you cannot.

According to [BitNodes](https://bitnodes.21.co/), as of this writing there are over 5000 full nodes on the network, all of them providing this service for free.  This certainly seems to be sufficient for everyone who wants to use it.  So nobody is going to pay you money for a service they can have for free.  The effective market value of your services is zero.

It is possible that someday, as the cost of running a full node rises, there may not be enough people running free full nodes to satisfy the demand.  In that case, the market value of this service may increase above zero, and you might be able to get people to pay to use your node.  Note that if this happens, you'll probably also have to pay other nodes for the privilege of sharing their data with your customers, and getting them to help distribute data from your customers.  But at this point, this is pure speculation.

Comment: Note that Bitnodes' count does not reflect the real count of fully-validated nodes on the network but rather the clearnet-and-publicly-listening nodes count.  
A more accurate count can be found here [ https://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin/files/charts/software.html ], as of 2020 it's about 50 000 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A [Dash](http://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/dash/#charts) masternode is a full node that provides additional network services, and masternode owners get compensated. A Dash masternode must be collateralized with 1000 Dash.  Once a masternode is cryptographically collaterized, one can earn interest that gets paid to the public address of the 1000 collateralized Dash. This is a form of Proof of Stake (PoS). Current [count](https://dash-stats.firebaseapp.com/) of active Dash masternodes. One may outsource masternodes to specialized masternode [virtual private server providers](https://dashpay.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1867885).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start getting paid for your service you must get a list of those 5000 full Nodes providers and reach out to each one and get them to collaborate with you to take down their Nodes until Bitcoin agree to pay a percentage to at least cover the ware and tear of your computer, internet access, Electricity consumption and management of each node.

I am sure that this service is not free for you and so, it should not be free for Bitcoin or anyone else.

I am not advocating for mutining, I am just making it clear everyone else that Bicoin is not going to voluntarily start paying for something if they can get it for free.

If you can get at least half of the 5k nodes provides to co-operate with you, you'll be in business. Good luck. :)

Comment: Even if we could get a significant number of people to agree, taking down our non-mining full nodes as a form of protest wouldn't have the desired effect.  The miners would just continue along despite the reduction in the number of non-mining full nodes.  SVP wallets would be obliged to connect to the miners directly,

Answer (score -1):

you have the solution running your own code and application doing all the work 
1. have a bitcoin wallet to generate each customer it's payment address
2. flush the address on the payment screen for each customer
3. check the blockchain to see if the address received the transaction 
4. wait for confirmations

or, connect to bitcoin payment service provider (like paypal for money)

Comment: I'm too lazy to be bothered to write my own code.